# Error appear after runing my flask code : jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, html, flask

when i run the below code i have this error:
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '%'

please note that i copied this code from you-tuber which working with him properly
i review my code and checked the syntax but i did not find any error so please any one can help

this is the python file:

```
  from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Corey Schafer',
        'title': 'Blog Post 1',
        'content': 'First post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 20, 2018'
    },
    {
        'author': 'Jane Doe',
        'title': 'Blog Post 2',
        'content': 'Second post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 21, 2018'
    }
]


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)


@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and this is the html files:

home.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

about.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>About Page</h1>
{% endblock content %}
```

layout.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">

    {% if title %}
        <title>Flask Blog - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Flask Blog</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/">Flask Blog</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
              </ul>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, template inheritance goes something like this

```
{% block content %}
your content
{% endblock %}
```

maybe you are ending the blocks wrong like `{% endblock content %}`

[look here for more explanation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/templateinheritance/)

Comment: can you show the error in more detail? try posting the whole error

Comment: you can find the full error in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TXMRTXVJg8RXiJ0eQkP5_CWAiAr8G3MW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: from layout.html head section remove title if else condition

Comment: i remove it then get this error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QGcbw5wQ9VCjTXLhB45E3SrK_56VnXFA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: add access to the drive

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QGcbw5wQ9VCjTXLhB45E3SrK_56VnXFA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry by mistake

Comment: errors says you haven't removed {{% if title %}} from layout.html